# NET_ERR responded from Jenkins server when Webhook sends request to Jenkins server to do the build

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have Bitbucket Cloud, Webhooks is configured to connect to Jenkins server. On Jenkins server, Bitbucket Branch Source plugin, Git plugin are both installed.

When add Webhooks at Bitbucket cloud given repository, have tried putting Jenkins server https://[IP:Port]/ or https://[IP:Port]/bitbucket-hook/.

On Jenkins configuration, after **Bitbucket branch source plugin** is installed, **Git plugin configuration** is gone from **Manage Plugin** -> **Configure System** page. I didn't see the place to specify 
1. repository name
2. name of Webhook
3. branch name

That could be the reason why NET_ERR is thrown. But why missing the portion that I expected from **Configure System** page? Jenkins version number is 2.190.3

Thanks